# Authentication flow for Google Sheets API v4 on cli webserver

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api

I went through the Google Sheets API v4 for Python and created a script which reads data from a spreadsheet. I'm able to perform the authenticate flow on my laptop but not able to do it in my server with just cli interface.

When running the script for the first time, I'm able to complete the authentication flow via browser on my laptop but I'm unable to perform the same on my webserver which has just cli interface. On older versions of the sheets api I was able to give extra parameter while running the script and then visit the url via external browser and it used to generate the token file but copying the url and trying to workout the same way as old versions doesn't seem to work with v4.

```
$ python google-sheets.py --noauth_local_webserver
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is suitable for your situation, for example, how about this flow? 1. Create the file including the refresh token at the PC which can use the browser. 2. Copy the created file to the PC which cannot use the browser. 3. Run the script using the copied file including the refresh token. If this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: To be honest, that's the exact workaround I took but I'm looking to find if there's more appropriate solution.

Comment: I apologize I couldn't help. Can I ask you about the detail information of ``more appropriate solution``?